# SVG shows content outside of viewBox when it fills whole browser window

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to have an inline SVG fill the whole width of the browser window. The SVG has some content outside of the viewBox. This is the SVG file: http://pastebin.com/F5irDNai

What happens when I set the width to 100% is that the content outside of the viewBox gets visible:

```
svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3w2hy8kv/1/
The red rectangle is the viewBox boundary.

What I want is to have the viewBox of the SVG fill whole browser window horizontally without the content outside of the viewBox appearing. Is that possible?

Comment: doesn't overflow: hidden; work?

Comment: No, I have tried that on both the parent element, body and the svg itself and I does not hide the content outside viewBox.

Whenever the width is larger than the viewBox the content outside of the viewBox appears.

Comment: You need to look at the preserveAspectRatio attribute. Also try putting a border on the div to see where that goes. Other things to look for: svgomg to optimize your svg, sara souedan's articles on preserveAspectRatio. closest to what you want I got with `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice"` on the svg element

Comment: overflow:hidden clips to the viewport not the viewbox... you can use a clipPath to clip to the viewbox... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074216/svg-viewbox-overflow-hidden-crop

Comment: @Ruskin: preserveAspectRatio was the key. Thanks!

Comment: @HolgerWill: That would probably work as well but I think preserveAspectRatio is easier.

Comment: preserveAspectRatio only works in the special case where your viewbox ratio matches your viewport ratio (width and height)... as I said svgs clip to the viewport not the viewbox. If you want to clip to the viewbox you need a clipPath...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Ruskin and [SVG viewbox showing showing off-screen items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151600/svg-viewbox-showing-showing-off-screen-items?rq=1) who got me in the right direction.

Attribute added to the svg element:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"
```

It also works adding this attribute with JavaScript.

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#theSVG svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/74cc07m1/1/

EDIT:
Fiddle updated with optimized SVG: https://jsfiddle.net/74cc07m1/2/

Comment: Awesome ... now just optimize the svg with https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/